# JQuery autocomplete based on select option value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am very very new to JQuery and Javascript. I have implemented autocomplete functionality that retrieves the data from remote datasource( Mysql + PHP) using jQuery Demo. 
I am stuck at the part where the mysql query triggered by the php script is binded to the drop down menu option.

So if I select "comments" from one of the option value, how do I bind it to the search textbox with id="search_term".

```
<label>Select Search parameter:
    <select id="search_parameter" name="search_parameter">
        <option value="Sample name">Sample Name</option>
        <option value="Location name">Location Name</option>
        <option value="comments">Comments</option>
    </select>
</label>

<label> Search Term:<input type="text" id="search_term" required name="search_term" maxlength=30></label>
```

Now if I select option value as "comments" it should trigger the PHP script that queries the comment field. But I am not sure how do I get the conditional statement into JQuery. I am not getting success with

```
$(function(){
    $('#search_parameter').change(function(){
        if (this.value == "comments") {
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $('#search_term').autocomplete({source:'search_comments.php', minLength:2});
            });
        else if( this.value =="Sample name") {
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $('#search_term').autocomplete({source:'search_sample_name.php', minLength:2});
            });
}
```

I am not sure if this is the right approach. I apologize if this question is not  worthy of stackoverflow.com.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend initializing the autocomplete widget once on the `input`. You can use the `option` method to set the `source` when the value of the `select` element is changed:

```
$(function () {
    $("#search_term").autocomplete({
        source: "",
        minLength: 2
    });

    $("#search_parameter").change(function () {
        if (this.value === "Sample name") {
            $("#search_term").autocomplete("option", "source", "search_sample_name.php");
        } else if (this.value === "comments") {
            $("#search_term").autocomplete("option", "source", "search_comments.php");
        }
    }).change(); // Trigger the "change" event to set the source correctly the first time.
});
```

You can make this even more robust by using a `data-*` attribute on each option that indicates which source to use:

**HTML:**

```
<label>Select Search parameter:
    <select id="search_parameter" name="search_parameter">
        <option value="Sample name" data-autocomplete="search_sample_name.php">Sample Name</option>
        <option value="Location name" data-autocomplete="search_locations.php">Location Name</option>
        <option value="comments" data-autocomplete="search_comments.php">Comments</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function () {
    $("#search_term").autocomplete({
        source: ''
    });

    $("#search_parameter").change(function () {
        var selectedSource = $(this).find("option:selected").data("autocomplete");

        $("#search_term").autocomplete("option", "source", selectedSource);
    }).change();
});
```

Comment: Data attribute seems more succinct than conditional approach. On the side note: I think Javascript tends to rely less on conditional statements and more on the tags and ID/attribute. Is there a substance to this question?

Comment: I think it all depends on what you're doing. But I agree with you, I would use the `data-*` approach in this case.